# Using Arduino Uno to log GSM Air interface messages

Tags: arduino, gsm, cdma

Is it possible to log the GSM Air interface messages that are sent between a GSM module and the GSM/WCMDA network using an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno)?

Basically, I want to log/record all the GSM messages of the Air interface (for example, paging command, CM service request, location update, etc.) that are sent between a GSM module and the network in order to perform say, location update, initiate a call, etc. using the Arduino Uno and a data logger.

Comment: Maybe better asked on electronics.stackexchange.com?  What do you want to log this to: a PC, a standalone Aruino-powered logger, something else?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be best if it is logged to a stand alone Arduino-powered logger. Sparkfun has a module called the logmatic which is a data logger. but even if there were no standalone loggers I could still work with logging these data to a PC.  At the moment my concern is whether the Arduino could be programmed to receive these messages from the GSM module.  In other words, whether the GSM module has an interface to push the GSM Air interface messages through to Arduino.

Comment: Is there a particular GSM module you have in mind?

Comment: I had Cellular Shield with SM5100B (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9607 ) in mind which according to the description has a cellular module included.

Answer (score 0):

I ordered the equipments and tested it but unfortunately, it was not possible.
The chipset processes all the messages upto and including layer 7 and then passes the result to the arduino.

Answer (score 0):

sound more like jtag or gdb territory to log messages at that low of a level